# Use a custom WiX Template for JavaFX deployment

Tags: java, deployment, javafx, ant, wix

I'm trying to deploy ma JavaFX Project as an msi installer wit WiX Toolset with e(fx)clipse.

I created an build.xml with packaging type .msi, added a package folder to the build folder with my icons in it and also added

```
<path id="fxant">
  <filelist>
    ...
    <file name="${basedir}"/>
  </filelist>
</path>
```

to make the icons available (according to http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/)

Of course i installed WiX Toolset 3.10 and added it to the Path enviroment variable.

If I run the build.xml script now it gives me an msi installer, but if i start it it doesn't do anything.

I want to know if it is possible to have a custom .wxs template.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just need to add a .wxs file to your build package, similar to how you added your icons.

To get a wxs file to customize, use the default on that is generated. To know where it is stored, you need to turn on verbose mode and run the build.xml.
It will print out the location like so to the console:

```
Executable File Name: C:\Users\chavgx\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler643321847130297895\images\win-msi.image\appName\appName.exe
  Config files are saved to C:\Users\chavgx\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler643321847130297895\windows. Use them to customize package.
  Using default package resource [WiX config file]  (add package/windows/appName.wxs to the class path to customize)
```